# How to update a variable on keypress with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to modify some code to work for me.
I have a running application with tkinter and I can update both scores (blue and red) when I am pressing the buttons, but I want to find a way how to do this via keypress ? For example to increase the score for the reds when pressing "r" and increase the score for the blue when pressing "b"
Tried different things from google but without any luck.
Could someone have a look and give me some hints?

```
import tkinter as tk

from time import sleep

window = tk.Tk()

window.configure(bg='black')
window.geometry('1024x600')
window.overrideredirect(True)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

scoreRed = 0
scoreBlue = 0

global BlueWonBoolean
global RedWonBoolean
BlueWonBoolean = False
RedWonBoolean = False

RedText = tk.StringVar()
BlueText = tk.StringVar()

RedText.set(str(scoreRed))
BlueText.set(str(scoreBlue))



def addBlue():
    global scoreBlue
    scoreBlue += 1
    BlueText.set(str(scoreBlue))
    if scoreBlue == 21:
        global BlueWonBoolean
        BlueWonBoolean = True
        print("\nBlue Won!!!\nBLUE | RED\n " + str(scoreBlue) + "  :  " + str(scoreRed))

        global BlueWon
        BlueWon = tk.Label(text="Blue Won!!!",
                           foreground="white",
                           background="black",
                           width=10,
                           height=10)
        BlueWon.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)


def addRed():
    global scoreRed
    scoreRed += 1
    RedText.set(str(scoreRed))
    if scoreRed == 21:
        global RedWonBoolean
        RedWonBoolean = True
        print("\nRed Won!!!\nRED | BLUE\n" + str(scoreRed) + "  :  " + str(scoreBlue))

        global RedWon
        RedWon = tk.Label(text="Red Won!!!",
                          foreground="white",
                          background="black",
                          width=10,
                          height=10)
        RedWon.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)


def resetScore():
    global scoreRed
    global scoreBlue
    global BlueWonBoolean
    global RedWonBoolean
    scoreRed = 0
    scoreBlue = 0
    RedText.set(str(scoreRed))
    BlueText.set(str(scoreBlue))
    BlueLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)
    RedLabel.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X)

    if BlueWonBoolean == True:
        BlueWon.destroy()
        BlueWonBoolean = False
    elif RedWonBoolean == True:
        RedWon.destroy()
        RedWonBoolean = False

    BlueButton = tk.Button(window, text="Blue Point", bg="white", fg="yellow", width=30, height=15, command=addBlue)
    RedButton = tk.Button(window, text="Red Point", bg="red", fg="black", width=30, height=15, command=addRed)
    ResetButton = tk.Button(window, text="Reset", width=10, height=3, command=resetScore)

    BlueLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)
    RedLabel.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X)


def Quit():
    exit()


while True:
    try:

        BlueLabel = tk.Label(
            textvariable=BlueText,
            foreground="white",
            background="black",
            width=10,
            height=5
        )

        RedLabel = tk.Label(
            textvariable=RedText,
            foreground="white",
            background="black",
            width=10,
            height=5
        )

        BlueButton = tk.Button(window, text="Blue Point", bg="black", fg="WHITE", width=30, height=15, command=addBlue)
        RedButton = tk.Button(window, text="Red Point", bg="black", fg="WHITE", width=30, height=15, command=addRed)
        ResetButton = tk.Button(window, text="Reset", bg="black", fg="WHITE", width=10, height=3, command=resetScore)
        quitButton = tk.Button(window, text="Quit ", bg="black", fg="WHITE", command=Quit)

        # image = tk.PhotoImage(file="cornHole.png")
        # imageLabel = tk.Label(image=image)

        BlueLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)
        RedLabel.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X)

        BlueButton.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)
        RedButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.X)
        # imageLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        quitButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        ResetButton.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        window.bind("<Escape>", exit)
        window.mainloop()
    except:
        exit()
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? `window.overrideredirect(True)` prevents the window to get keyboard focus in linux.

Comment: What exactly did you try yet? Also, does pressing Escape give you the wanted results? If so, then why don't you keep using `window.bind("your-keys", function_to_call)`?

Comment: @JulianKirsch because it is not working in this way. Don`t know why I already tried.

Comment: @j_4321 I am on Windows 7

Comment: @VeleslavPanov Ok, then it should work, you just have to read the [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) on keyboard bindings. BTW don't use a `while True` loop with tkinter, the `mainloop()` is already playing this role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keybindings to run the function when a key is pressed

```
window.bind("b", addblue )
```

Here are a website and a video explaining them further

https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLnNPjL1U2g

Comment: Did they help you?

Comment: Another question. Do you know how to update canvas in tkinter ? I have the following issue that my variables are overlapped on keypress and I cannot fix this ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean. Would you mind explaining further?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Veleslav Panov and welcome to Stack Overflow! You can use the `.bind()`method available in tkinter t achieve this task. For example, imagine that you want to update variable on pressing the `Enter` or the `Return` key. Then use this:

```
def function_name(*args):
    variable_name +=1
    #say the updation to be done here
name_of_window.bind("<Return>", function_name)
```

Note: Instead of `*args`, you can use any variable name, the only thing needed is that there should be at least one variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use us `.bind()` to bind any key to any function, the only requirment is that the function will have some argument, for example 'event'.

```
def function(event):
    #Do something
window.bind("<Return>", function)
```

This way, every time the button (in this case Enter) is pressed, the function will be called. In your case you would bind 2 buttons, 'r' and 'b', to 2 functions to add score to each of the sides.

Here is a link with some examples:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-binding-function-in-tkinter/